# Why have I connection failed when I try to connect to my localhost?

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide

I have an esp32 with one sensor(BMP280) connected and one database where I want to storage three parameters: temperature, atmospheric pressure and altitude. The database is on localhost with 8080 port. I cannot to connect at my localhost and I have connection failed. I have tried to put at host the ip address 0.0.0.0 or localhost:8080 and it doesn't work. What is the problem?
I attach my code below:

```cpp
#include <BMP280_DEV.h>

#include <WiFi.h>

float temperature, pressure, altitude;
BMP280_DEV bmp280;

const char * ssid = "*******";
const char * password = "*********";
const char * host = "127.0.0.1";
const int port = 8080;
const int watchdog = 5000;
unsigned long previousMillis = millis();

void init_wifi() {
    //We start by connecting to a Wi-Fi network
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}
void setup() {

    Serial.begin(115200);
    bmp280.begin(BMP280_I2C_ALT_ADDR);
    //bmp280.setPresOversampling(OVERSAMPLING_X4);    
    //bmp280.setTempOversampling(OVERSAMPLING_X1);    
    //bmp280.setIIRFilter(IIR_FILTER_4);              
    bmp280.setTimeStandby(TIME_STANDBY_2000MS);
    bmp280.startNormalConversion();

    init_wifi();
}

void loop() {
    if (bmp280.getMeasurements(temperature, pressure, altitude)) {
        Serial.print(temperature);
        Serial.print(F("*C   "));
        Serial.print(pressure);
        Serial.print(F("hPa   "));
        Serial.print(altitude);
        Serial.println(F("m"));
        delay(20000);
    }

    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis > watchdog) {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
        WiFiClient client;

        if (!client.connect(host, port)) {
            Serial.println("Connection Failed");
            return;
        }

        String url = "/test_bmp280/index.php?temp=";
        url += temperature;
        url += "&pres=";
        url += pressure;
        url += "&alt=";
        url += altitude;
        client.print(String("GET ") + url + "HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
            "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
            "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        unsigned long timeout = millis();
        while (client.available() == 0) {
            if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
                Serial.println(">>>Client Timeout !");
                client.stop();
                return;
            }
        }

        while (client.available()) {
            String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
            Serial.print(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `const char * host = "127.0.0.1";` That doesn't look correct. That address is the loopback address. You need to get the IP address of the server.

Comment: My database server is on the loopback address and from this cause I put this address.

Comment: If you use the loopback, you are telling the ESP to connect to itself. That is not what you want. You need to know the server's ip address.

Comment: Okay, my bad. I found the server's ip address in cmd but it doesn't work... :(

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I turned off the firewall and now is working. Thanks for answers!